# plugging 0.1 inch header socket pin

Tags: connector

I'd like to convert a non-keyed 0.1 inch pin header/socket connector pair into a "keyed" version by doing the following: Clip off a single unused pin in the pin header, and permanently plug the equivalent pin hole on the socket. Due to constraints, I am unable to just replace the header/sockets with new shrouded/keyed parts.

Does anybody have a method/technique for plugging the socket hole? I was thinking of dunking the clipped-off pin in some epoxy and shoving it in the hole, but wanted recommendations if there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3):

Just buy the matching plugs, and plug the holes.

They come on a [carrier](https://www.tme.eu/de/en/details/mx-15-04-0292/pin-headers/molex/15-04-0292/) to bend/snip off, or [individually](https://www.tme.eu/de/en/details/nsdr-key/pin-headers/ninigi/)

[image: plug]
<sup>image from the TME product page on individual plugs above</sup>